# How to access a conditionally added property in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My React Component `Loader` get some props.

Property `contentAlign` exists only when property `local` exists and `local === 'relative'`;

I can’t put `contentAlign` in `props` as I get an error and I can’t access `contentAlign` in the component (style on `<div>`) because I don’t accept it in `props`

How do I access `contentAlign`?

```
export type LoaderProps = {
  className?: string;
  background?: string;
  size?: number;
} & (
    | {
        local?: Nullable<boolean>;
      }
    | {
        local: 'relative';
        contentAlign: LoaderContentAlign;
      }
  );

const Loader: React.FC<LoaderProps> = ({
  className,
  background = 'blue',
  local = false,
  size = 30,
  ...props
}: LoaderProps) => {
  console.log('props ', props);
  
  return (
    <div
        className={{local === 'relative' && `loader_content-${props.contentAlign}}}`
    >
      Content
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: please provide reproducible example

Comment: @captain-yossarian All you need to know from this example is that the contentAlign property only exists when local === 'relative'

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to simply have `contentAlign` as an optional property `contentAlign?: LoaderContentAlign` and check for the `local === 'relative'` condition as needed when handling an object of type `LoaderProps`?

Comment: @captain-yossarian ok i edited example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript doesn't apply smart casting when you use the destructuring assignment.
Try this:

```
const Loader: React.FC<LoaderProps> = ({
  className,
  background = 'blue',
  size = 30,
  ...props
}: LoaderProps) => {
  console.log('props ', props);
  
  return (
    <div
        className={{props.local === 'relative' && `loader_content-${props.contentAlign}}}`
    >
      Content
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [the `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in?retiredLocale=uk):

```
"contentAlign" in props && `loader_content-${props.contentAlign}`
```

*[Try it](https://tsplay.dev/N7g6qN)*.